# How to stretch listbox height using XAML in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

My window is a Grid, the 2nd row stretches to fill the window.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The content of the 2nd row is a StackPanel. I imitated the solution of a similar question on SO and it doesn't work for me: height of listbox doesn't stretch to fill the 2nd row. What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="lbStackPanel" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" Height="{Binding ElementName=lbStackPanel, Path=ActualHeight}">
        ...
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need a `StackPanel` there?

Just take it out and the row should size correctly.

Comment: As I wrote, I needed to derive the height of the listbox from the stackpanel as the solution I saw on SO. Is there a different approach?

Comment: @user763554: The `StackPanel` serves no purpose except making the row's own layout useless, where did anyone suggest that? You probably took it the wrong way and that was a workaround to solve a very different problem.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely brilliant. I took it out and it worked for me.

Comment: @user763554: Phew, and the Grid is clean again.

Answer (score 4):

Ignore the StackPanel and just have a ListBox that takes up the second row (Grid.Row="1").   Set the values of HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment for the ListBox to "Stretch".   The height of the ListBox will then take up the entire second row.   This is much easier then binding to the StackPanel's height.